# How to extend one of the facet created with facet_wrap and executed with ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplotly

I would like to be able to display one of the windows that were created with `facet_wrap` by zooming or selecting the window on the web page created with `ggplotly`.
Can something like this be done without using a Shiny app?

An example would be:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, 
            color = factor(cyl), shape = factor(cyl))) +
     geom_point() +
     facet_wrap(~factor(cyl))

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

After zoom I like something like this that takes up the entire page.:

[image]

Thank you very much for taking the time to read the query.
Best

Comment: If you are using R Studio, you can open the ggplotly facet_wrap visualization in a new window by clicking on "Zoom". When that opens, you can now zoom in on different aspects of your interactive visualization using the control widgets in plotly.

Comment: Thank you @Idiaye but your answer is not what I am looking for.